# c#- How can I past PointF in to DrawString?

Tags: c#

### c#- How can I past PointF in to DrawString?

I try to past PointF into DrawString but it is not provide me.This is the code but ti is not provide me how can I do?

```
string txt = "A long line we're trying to fit inside a rectangle with custom line spacing";

          Font font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
          SizeF fit = new SizeF(200, font.Height);
          StringFormat fmt = StringFormat.GenericTypographic;
          PointF pointf = new PointF(55,21);

          //Rectangle ss =  new Rectangle(new PointF(155.0F, 225.0F),txt);

          int spacing = (int)(1.5 * font.Height);
          int line = 0;

          for (int ix = 0; ix < txt.Length; ) {
            int chars, lines;

            e.Graphics.MeasureString(txt.Substring(ix), font, fit, fmt, out chars, out lines);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(txt.Substring(ix, chars), font, Brushes.Black, pointf, spacing * line);
            ++line;
            ix += chars;

          }
```

**Please show me by code!**

Comment: What are you trying to do? There are two `DrawString` methods that take a `PointF`. One takes only four parameters and the other requires a `StringFormat` as the last parameter. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.110).aspx. Are you trying to update the `Y` field in the `pointf` so that the next line displays correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(txt.Substring(ix, chars), font, Brushes.Black, pointf);
++line;
ix += chars;
// Set up for the next line.
pointf.Y = pointf.Y + (lines*font.Height) + spacing;
```

Note that I removed the last parameter to the `DrawString` call, and added code to update `pointf.Y`.